# How to get information of CPU temperature

Tags: terminal, mac, apple-silicon

I want to know how to get temperature of CPU (on MacBook Pro with Apple Silicon).
It should be able to get it simply on **Terminal**.
But Cases on Mac with **Apple Silicon**, **SMC** can't be used.
Please tell me, if you know **commands** that work on Macs with **Apple Silicon**.

Comment: Why? Checking the CPU temperature is a thing of the past. You might have needed to do it on Intel, because the CPUs were ovens; but not on AS.